# Getting undefined when trying to log a function in the console

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
var object = {
    name: 'hello!',
    func: function(){
        console.log(this);
    }
}

console.log(object.func());
```

What I expect is to see the object whenever I log `object.func` and this does happen, I get to see the object. But right after the expected behavior I get unexpected behavior, `undefined` is shown.

Here's what the result looks like:

```
{ name: 'hello!', func: [Function: func] }
undefined
```

What's the reason this is happening?

Side note:

I know I'm console logging something I shouldn't. However, this still doesn't explain to me why the `undefined`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`object.func()` doesn't return anything (so it returns undefined)

no need to log the result of `object.func()`

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to log the result of a function that does not return anything, hence, undefined. Just call `obj.func()` since you already handle the logging there anyway.

Or return a value on the function and log outside

```
var obj = {
    name: 'hello!',
    func: function(){
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: `console.log(obj.func());` returns two lines: 1 .`{name: "hello!", func: ƒ}` and 2. 
`undefined` . <-- why undefined?

Comment: @zipzit You are doing a `console.log` twice. First one inside your `.func()` method, second one outside the object, which is undefined since `obj.func()` does not return anything

Comment: I'm using your function.  `return this`, not the original submitted stuff.  Note: I'm using  browser console.

Comment: @zipzit If you are testing this on a browser's dev tools, it is because `console.log()` does not return anything either, that is why the browser shows undefined after the actual only `console.log(value)` that we wrote. If you try OP's submitted code, you will get three lines of results

Comment: My bad. Right you are. Thx.